# NoClassDefFoundError with parse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

Can somebody help me to fix this? When I run my android application on eclipse using a parse class created by Parse this issue appear.

03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.ParseCrashReporting
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at com.parse.starter.ParseApplication.onCreate(ParseApplication.java:17)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4684)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-27 11:43:35.378: E/AndroidRuntime(25869):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Try showing some more code

Comment: chek now, I edited the message problem.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError   comes  into picture  if  the classloader, which is responsible for dynamically loading classes, cannot find the .class file for the class that you're trying to use. It probably indicates that you haven't set the classpath option when executing your code.

[This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) explains how to set the classpath when you execute.