# Noclassdeffound exception com.parse.Parse in android

Tags: android

I am using parse-1.9.3.jar file in my eclipse tool for android development, but i am facing the noclassdeffoundexception while am running my app and my app is crashed. How to fix this issue, i am very much struggle in this point. 
I followed some points

1. I download the parse-1.9.3.jar, copy and paste in lib folder then right click on that parse-1.9.3.jar file then i clicked add to build, this way is not working
2. Right click project--> project properties--> order and export tab --> checked android private libraries and parse-1.9.3.jar file, this way not worked
3. [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.parse.Parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531640/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-parse-parse)  --> no use
4. [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)  --> NO use
5. [NoClassDefFoundError with parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29305916/noclassdeffounderror-with-parse) -->no use
6. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29 this is also no use

Please help for how to fix this error and run my app successfully

Thanks in advance